# Problem with Segmentation Fault with doing operations on class

Tags: c++

Sorry for variables not being all in engilsh. I have a problem when i try to do the `+=` operation on class called Uklad3.
It is initialized the same way as previous ones, but with this one the segmentation failure comes up when i try to do any operations on it.
Any sugestions how to fix it? I am not a proffesional programmer.
I sumbited the whole code because I know it might be little hard to read, I am learning and this is for ma class.
The goal of the operation `+=` is to add points from one coordinate system to the other. It is only the portion of the task but this is where I have a problem.

```
class punkt
{
private:
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;

public:
    
    punkt(){};
    string name;
    punkt(string,double,double,double);
    
    double getx() const {return x;}
    double gety() const {return y;}
    double getz() const {return z;}
};

punkt::punkt(string name_,double x_, double y_, double z_)
{
name=name_;
x=x_;
y=y_;
z=z_;    
}

class Uklad
{
public:
    static const int size = 10;
    punkt tablica[size];
    
    string uklad_name;
    
    void add(punkt);
    int licznik;
    Uklad(){licznik=0;};
    Uklad(string);
   
    Uklad & operator+=(const Uklad &var)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<var.licznik;i++)
        {
            tablica[licznik]=var.tablica[i];
            licznik++;    
        }
    }
    
    Uklad & operator-= (const Uklad &var)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<licznik;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<var.licznik;j++)
            {
                if((tablica[i].getx()==var.tablica[i].getx()) and (tablica[i].gety()==var.tablica[i].gety()) and (tablica[i].getz()==var.tablica[i].getz()))
                {
                    for(int k=i;k<licznik;k++)
                    {
                        tablica[k]=tablica[k+1];
                    }
                    licznik--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
   
        

};



Uklad::Uklad(string uklad_name_)
{
uklad_name=uklad_name_;
cout<<"Tworze uklad"<<endl;
}

void Uklad::add(punkt toAdd)
{
if(licznik<size)
{
    tablica[licznik]=toAdd;
    licznik++;
}
 }


}



ostream & operator<<(ostream &s, const punkt &Punkt)
{
cout<<Punkt.name<<" "<<Punkt.getx()<<" "<<Punkt.gety()<<" "<<Punkt.getz();
return s<<" ";
}

ostream & operator<<(ostream &s, const Uklad &uklad)
{

for(int i=0;i<uklad.licznik;i++)
{
   if(i==uklad.licznik-1) cout<<uklad.tablica[i]<<" ";
    else 
    cout<<uklad.tablica[i]<<"; ";
}
return s<<" ";
}



int main()
{
//1.
string name1,name2,name3;
cin>>name1;
cin>>name2;
Uklad uklad1(name1);
Uklad uklad2(name2);

//2.
const int M=2;
double xtemp, ytemp, ztemp;
string nametemp;
string xs,ys,zs;


for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
{
    cin>>nametemp;
    cin>>xtemp;
    cin>>ytemp;
    cin>>ztemp;
    
    punkt punktT(nametemp,xtemp,ytemp,ztemp);
    uklad1.add(punktT);
}

//3.
const int N=2;
double xtemp2, ytemp2, ztemp2;
string nametemp2;
string xs2,ys2,zs2;
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    cin>>nametemp2;
    cin>>xtemp2;
    cin>>ytemp2;
    cin>>ztemp2;
    
    punkt punktT2(nametemp2,xtemp2,ytemp2,ztemp2);
    uklad2.add(punktT2);
}

//4.
    cin>>name3;
    Uklad uklad3(name3);

//5.
 uklad3+=uklad1; 
 cout<<uklad3;


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

static const int size = 10;

You make array about 10 size and after all this loops you go out of range of the array. That's why you have this error. You can give it higher size. Or you can use vectors. In case of using array you must be sure you will not go out of range.

Comment: In which exatxt place you mean I exceed the size?

Comment: Because I am clueless how to fix this problem

Comment: Here  Uklad& operator+=(const Uklad &var)
 {
  for(int i=0;i<var.licznik;i++)
  {
   cout << licznik << " += ";
   tablica[licznik]=var.tablica[i];
   licznik++;
  }
  return *this;
 }   I added some code and i try to solve your problem

Comment: You didn't initialize licznik in constructor with string, so licznik could have random numbers.

Comment: Ohhh ok. I see where, such a silly mistake. Now I will know to always initialize the counter. I just need few tweaks in <code>-=</code> function and everyting should be working. Thank you very much. I just have one question, as I am slowly approaching pointer topic, what does <code>*this</code> in this case do? Does it just return the value of main operation for this function?

Comment: Uklad & operator-= (const Uklad &var) so Uklad is type what function should return. That's why i add it to your code. *this is mean return pointer to this object. If you create Uklad bla; This function return pointer to bla. I can be wrong so better check it in a reliable source

Answer (score 0):

I formated the code and add initializer to licznik. This code haven't segmentation fault error

```
class punkt
{
private:
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;

public:

    punkt(){};
    string name;
    punkt(string,double,double,double);

    double getx() const {return x;}
    double gety() const {return y;}
    double getz() const {return z;}
};

punkt::punkt(string name_,double x_, double y_, double z_)
{
    name=name_;
    x=x_;
    y=y_;
    z=z_;
}

class Uklad
{
public:
    static const int size = 10;
    punkt tablica[size];

    string uklad_name = "";

    void add(punkt);
    int licznik = 0;
    Uklad(){licznik=0;};
    Uklad(string);

    Uklad& operator+=(const Uklad &var)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<var.licznik;i++)
        {
            cout << licznik << " += ";
            tablica[licznik]=var.tablica[i];
            licznik++;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Uklad & operator-= (const Uklad &var)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<licznik;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<var.licznik;j++)
            {
                cout << i << " -=";
                if((tablica[i].getx()==var.tablica[i].getx()) and (tablica[i].gety()==var.tablica[i].gety()) and (tablica[i].getz()==var.tablica[i].getz()))
                {
                    for(int k=i;k<licznik;k++)
                    {
                        tablica[k]=tablica[k+1];
                    }
                    licznik--;
                }
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }
};


Uklad::Uklad(string uklad_name_)
{
    licznik = 0;
    uklad_name=uklad_name_;
    cout << "Tworze uklad" << endl;
}

void Uklad::add(punkt toAdd)
{
    if(licznik<size)
    {
        tablica[licznik]=toAdd;
        licznik++;
    }
}





ostream & operator<<(ostream &s, const punkt &Punkt)
{
    cout<<Punkt.name<<" "<<Punkt.getx()<<" "<<Punkt.gety()<<" "<<Punkt.getz();
    return s<<" ";
}

ostream & operator<<(ostream &s, const Uklad &uklad)
{

    for(int i=0;i<uklad.licznik;i++)
    {
        if(i==uklad.licznik-1) cout<<uklad.tablica[i]<<" ";
        else
            cout<<uklad.tablica[i]<<"; ";
    }
    return s<<" ";
}


int main()
{
    //1.
    string name1,name2,name3;
    cin>>name1;
    cin>>name2;
    Uklad uklad1(name1);
    Uklad uklad2(name2);

    //2.
    const int M=2;
    double xtemp, ytemp, ztemp;
    string nametemp;
    string xs,ys,zs;


    for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
    {
        cin>>nametemp;
        cin>>xtemp;
        cin>>ytemp;
        cin>>ztemp;

        punkt punktT(nametemp,xtemp,ytemp,ztemp);
        uklad1.add(punktT);
    }

    //3.
    const int N=2;
    double xtemp2, ytemp2, ztemp2;
    string nametemp2;
    string xs2,ys2,zs2;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        cin>>nametemp2;
        cin>>xtemp2;
        cin>>ytemp2;
        cin>>ztemp2;

        punkt punktT2(nametemp2,xtemp2,ytemp2,ztemp2);
        uklad2.add(punktT2);
    }

    //4.
    cin>>name3;
    Uklad uklad3(name3);

    //5.
    uklad3+=uklad1;
    cout<<uklad3;
    return 0;
}
```